# installing tortunel missing Boost file?

Tags: boost, tor

Following the steps in this [website](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-tortunnel-quickly-encrypt-internet-traffic-0131169/) to install Tortunnel, on step 1 point 5 where i am suppose to run make && make install, i get the following ;

```
In file included from TorProxy.cpp:30:
./TorProxy.h:33:10: fatal error: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [TorProxy.o] Error 1
```

after that i made sure to install Boost with brew on Mac

and then again i ran the same command but got the same out come ?
i was able to locate the exact file in the Boot folder and confirm that it is there, but not sure if it in the right location since it is not in the tortunnel folder, and i am running the command from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Brew didn't install the boost libraries to your C compiler's include path so you'll need to specify it when you go to configure the software.

Since you said you were able to find where the Boost libs were installed, try:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/boost" ./configure [opts]
```

In the above command, `/path/to/boost` would be the directory where the `boost` folder is located that contains `shared_ptr.hpp`.  So say that were `/opt/shared/brew/include/boost` then use `/opt/shared/brew/include` in the configure command (I have no idea where Brew puts stuff so this path is totally made up for this answer).